# MATCH (N) RETURN (N) on Neo4J shows price of the item instead the name on the graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am executing MATCH (N) RETURN (N) on Neo4J and instead of showing me the name of the item, it shows me the price

```
CREATE (motor:componente {nombre: "Motor", precio: 1000})
CREATE (carcaza:pieza {nombre: "Carcaza", costo: 220 })
CREATE (tornillo:pieza {nombre: "Tornillo", costo: 25 })
CREATE (rulemán:pieza {nombre: "Ruleman", costo: 140 })
CREATE (buje:pieza {nombre: "Buje", costo: 83 })
CREATE (bobina:repueso {nombre: "Bobina", costo: 300})
CREATE (motor) - [:COMPUESTO_POR] -> (carcaza)
MATCH (N) RETURN (N)
```

I expected to show me the graph relationships by the name of the items

Comment: Where is it showing?

Comment: Im running it on Neo4J browser.